# Changing NODATA value GeoTIFF with ArcPy of ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcpy, geotiff-tiff, spatial-analyst, arcgis-pro, raster-calculator

I'm using a tool in ArcPy for Python 3 (ArcGIS Pro) which applies an operation to a raster file in GeoTIFF format.

```py
condicion = '("{}"  - {}) / {}'.format(input_image,n,m)
arcpy.gp.RasterCalculator_sa(condicion, output_image)
```

Where `n` and `m` are doubles and `input_image` and `output_image` strings referring to the GeoTiff file.

It works fine but it changes the NODATA value from `-3,40282306074E+38` (NODATA value used by ArcPy in Python2 and ArcMap) to `-1.79769313486231571e+308` (nodata value used by ArcPy in Python3 and ArcGIS Pro).

But I want to preservate the previous NODATA value, I'm trying to use `arcpy.SetRasterProperties_management` tool. Is it possible to use it this way?

```py
condicion = '("{}"  - {}) / {}'.format(input_image,n,m)
arcpy.gp.RasterCalculator_sa(condicion, output_image)
arcpy.SetRasterProperties_management(output_image, nodata='1 -3,40282306074E+38')
```

This code does not return any errors, but neither does the raster NODATA value change.

Comment: According to the documentation, that is the way to use it. Are you getting any error?

Comment: I don't get any error, but the intended chage has no effect. According to the documentation, this tool takes a Raster Layer or a Mosaic Layer as input. The example described in it is similar to what I try to do: `arcpy.SetRasterProperties_management("\\cpu\data\srtm.tif", "ELEVATION", "1 50 400 5 28" , "#" , "#")`

Comment: What about the ',' in your '-3,40282306074E+38'? Does that need to be changed to a '.'?